# How to use RSelenium to Login to a Website on Windows machine

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping

**Original Question: Viewing docker image secret on Windows machine**
*I updated the question when I got a solution without docker*

I'm following this [RSelenium tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-docker.html#using-selenium-docker-images) and I'm getting stuck when I'm trying to login to the container using tight VNC.

I need to obtain the image secret but the command I'm told to run is a bit foreign to me (windows machine)

```
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy install \
    x11vnc \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && mkdir -p ~/.vnc \
&& x11vnc -storepasswd secret ~/.vnc/passwd
```

For background my actual goal was to use R to login to a website and scrape some data. This lead me to RSelenium, which requires Docker.

**Solution with a lot of help from chinsoon12**
This solution gets around the problem of requiring the use of docker and just allows me to get access to the browser via RSelenium

```
#Install firefox
#Download geckodriver and unzip the exe here c:\bin\geckodriver
#start Selenium server by opening a command prompt and then type
#cd ~YOUR_R_PATH~\library\RSelenium\bin
#Download selenium server into the above location http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ 
#java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar

remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://www2.commsec.com.au/Public/HomePage/Login.aspx")

#send username
username <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "ct100_cpContent_txtLogin")
username$clearElement()
username$sendKeysToElement(list("My_User_Name"))

#send password and Enter
passwd <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "ct100_cpContent_fakepassword")
passwd$clearElement()
passwd$sendKeysToElement(list("My_Password", "\uE007"))
```

Comment: can you share the website link?

Comment: [Here it is](https://www2.commsec.com.au/Public/HomePage/Login.aspx)

Comment: The password for the VNC is `secret` as noted in the vignette.

Comment: @jdharrison
 I don't think I know what that means. I've tried typing in "secret" as the password when tightVNC prompts me and that fails. So I'm at a loss

Comment: Yes the password is `secret` as can been seen in the dockerfile https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/StandaloneFirefoxDebug/Dockerfile . If you are having problems with the docker image consider filing an issue on the docker github page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below. Let me know which step fail and the error message. I will try to help.

```
#start Selenium server by opening a command prompt and then type
#cd ~YOUR_R_PATH~\library\RSelenium\bin
#java -jar selenium-server-standalone-x.xx.x.jar

remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()

remDr$navigate("https://www2.commsec.com.au/Public/HomePage/Login.aspx")

#send username
username <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "ct100_cpContent_txtLogin")
username$sendKeysToElement(list("My_User_Name"))

#send password and Enter
passwd <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "ct100_cpContent_fakepassword")
passwd$sendKeysToElement(list("My_Password", "\uE007"))
```

Comment: Thankyou!
I needed to install firefox and gecko driver first and then
added a command to clear the text element before entering login details.

I'll update my question with a full solution.

I guess I can forget about the Docker part for now =)