# How to do login on website using R and to check login success?

Tags: r, csv, authentication, download, html

I need to just a simple log in the webpage [login page](https://lgloz050.lss.emc.com:58443/APG/) and how do I check that login is successful or not?

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tictoc)
library(data.table)
library(properties)
library(futile.logger)
library(crayon)
library(XML)
library(methods)
library(compare)
library(tictoc)
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

server.name <- "lgloz050.lss.emc.com"
port.no <- "58443"
default.path <- "/APG/lookup/"

set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))

config.s3 <- fread("Configuration_modify.csv")
config.s3$bc <- config.s3$testReport
config.s3$testReport <- gsub(">>","/", config.s3$testReport)
config.s3$testReport <- gsub(" ","%20", config.s3$testReport)

config.s3$link <- paste("https://",server.name,":",port.no,default.path,config.s3$testReport,"/report.csv", sep = "")

properties = read.csv2("Configuration.properties",sep = "=", blank.lines.skip = TRUE,header = FALSE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE  )
colnames(properties) <- c("key", "value")

config.s3$link <- gsub("$","PH_", config.s3$link)
#config.s3$link

for(i in 1:nrow(properties)){
  if(startsWith(properties[i,1],"$")){
    print(properties[i,1])
    for (j in 1: nrow(config.s3)) {
      config.s3[j]$link = gsub(paste("PH_",substring(trimws(properties[i,1]),2),sep = "")
                           ,trimws(properties[i,2]),config.s3[j]$link,ignore.case = TRUE)
    }
  }

}

result <- config.s3[, list(bc,TestCaseID,link),]

auth <- function(link,user.name="*****", password="******"){
  res <- GET(link,add_headers("accept"="text/json"))
  res <- POST('https://lgloz050.lss.emc.com:58443/APG/j_security_check'
              ,set_cookies=res$cookies
              ,body = "j_username=*****&j_password=******"
              ,add_headers("Content-Type" ="application/x-www-form-linkencoded" ))
  return(res)
}


fetch <- function(link,save.location,cookies){
  fetch.success = TRUE
  res <- GET(link
             ,add_headers("Authorization"="Basic **************")
             ,set_cookies=cookies)
  tryCatch({repot_data <- fread(content(res,"text"),header = TRUE);
  fwrite(data.frame(repot_data),save.location,row.names = FALSE);
  flog.info(green("'\u2713' - Fetch Completed successfully ..."))
  flog.info(paste("link : ",link))},
  error = function(e){fetch.success= FALSE; flog.error(paste("\u2715 - Not able to fetch data,file not created "))})

  return(fetch.success)
}

config.s3$save.location = sub("TruthData","testData",config.s3$truthReport,ignore.case = T)
response = auth(config.s3[1]$link)

# Function Call - fetch all the report data
result[,fetch:=FALSE]
result[,fetch.time:=0]
pb <- winProgressBar(title="Fetching Reports... ", label="0%", min=0, max=100, initial=0,width = 500)
for (i in 1:nrow(config.s3)) {
  tic()
  getWinProgressBar(pb)
  setWinProgressBar(pb, i*(100/nrow(config.s3)), label =paste(round(i*(100/nrow(config.s3)))," % \n",config.s3[i]$testReport))
  flog.info(paste("report",i,"started",config.s3[i]$link))
  fetch.success = fetch(config.s3[i]$link,config.s3[i]$save.location,response$cookies)
  t <- toc()
  t$toc
  result[i]$fetch <- fetch.success
  result[i]$fetch.time <- t$toc / 10000
}
close(pb)

result[,-c("link"),with=FALSE]
```

this is the code to fetch the CSV file but the file has HTML content of login page. please tell me where I am doing mistak and what i have to correct and modify to get the correct data.

suggest some procedure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using R shiny?

Comment: Use R package [httr] for creating a HTTP POST request. In the response you will get a [200 OK], If login was succesfully. The response comes normally in the header or the body, depending if you use POST or GET. Normally you would need authentication keys to login.

Comment: @anotherfred no, I am not using R shiny.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580133/how-to-use-rselenium-to-login-to-a-website-on-windows-machine

Comment: @boyaronur thanks a lot for such a good suggestion but I want to login Via API calls and then after need to download the CSV file.

Comment: @Toolbox thank you, after login, when I tried to fetch command to download the CSV file, the get downloaded but having HTML content of login page.

Comment: @Bhvaneet That is totally normal, or actually, often you receive the data in header or body, and would have to transform the data to the appropriate format. In my case I download data from API, get it in nested lists, perform unlist, change data to JSON format, and build a dataframe that I change to a timeseries.

Comment: @Bhaveet, it could also been that you need to perform things stepwise. To clarify, if you send a request for login, you will get an answer, eg. [200 OK]. That only means your credentials where fine and you can communicate with the API server. As second step, unless you have added all commands in one R-file, you would have to request for the actual data you want.

Comment: @Toolbox In the above code, what are those missing commands because of that the request of the actual data is not happening. what I need to include in the second step to put the request of a data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution which is as follows:

```
library(httr) 
library(rvest)
url <- "https://lgloz050.lss.emc.com:58443/APG/"
dn_url <- "https://lgloz050.lss.emc.com:58443/APG/lookup/Report%20Library/Amazon%20S3/Inventory/Accounts/report.csv"
session <-  html_session(url)
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
fl_fm <- set_values(form,
                        j_username = "*****",
                        j_password = "********")
main_page <- submit_form(session, fl_fm) 
download <- jump_to(main_page,dn_url)
writeBin(download$response$content, basename(dn_url))
```

on the execution of this code it will successfully log in and download the report and the downloaded report has the same content which is required. I do this for one file next I am trying to download the multiple files in one execution.

Thanks to you all for your support. let me know if there any other solution possible or any kind of modification is required in the above code.

Comment: this code works for me. I am trying to purpose the generalized approach these kind login and download problems. Suggest me if someone have any idea?