# R web scraping LOGIN issue

Tags: r, authentication, web-scraping, rvest

I want to login to my account, continue further on the website and scrape some information, but my r code with use of rvest package can not even log into the account..

```
link_of_login <- "https://www.fio.cz/e-broker/e-broker.cgi"
pgsession <- html_session(link_of_login)
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform, LOGIN_USERNAME="USERNAME", LOGIN_PASSWORD="PASSWORD")
submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
```

R returns: Error: form doesn't contain a action attribute.

I guess there might be a problem with the GET/POST method of submitting the login information as the POST method is this case. So is there any easy solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use RSelenium to Login to a Website on Windows machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580133/how-to-use-rselenium-to-login-to-a-website-on-windows-machine)

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you need to use **RSelenium** in this situation (because the page uses javascript to submit the form).

I believe, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43580133/how-to-use-rselenium-to-login-to-a-website-on-windows-machine) will be able to help you.